# Бегущая матрица

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как сделать бегущую "матрицу" в несколько столбиков с рандомными числами с помощью JS.

Comment: Что уже сами пробовали сделать?

Comment: @ MedvedevDev, к сожалению, в JS не силен и нашел только как выдать рандомное число, но без понятия как сделать постоянное изменение

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в вашем вопросе содержится сразу несколько подзадач. Их стоит разбить на несколько сообщений и пытаться решать по отдельности. С чем конкретно возникли сложности??

Comment: @mymedia основная задача вывести число в html страницу и постоянно его обновлять на новое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вы хотите что-то вроде этого - [Matrix Rain](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/matrix-rain-animation-html5-canvas-javascript), там и демо и исходный код на JavaScript. Достаточно объединить в один HTML как [здесь](https://pastebin.com/3WyJD8Tc) и всё заработает. Кстати, требуется поддержка HTML5 от браузера для работы этого скрипта.

Comment: Да, это практически то, что мне нужно, но у меня комп ругается на тот код. 2я строка js кода. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" не знаю что делать

Comment: @JohnyJay `<canvas id="c"></canvas>` - ето есть в разметке ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Да, привязал css и js и в body '<canvas id="c"></canvas>'

Comment: Запихните етот код в событие зaгрузки страницы

Comment: @JohnyJay Вот я объединил всё в одну HTML https://pastebin.com/3WyJD8Tc и у меня всё работает. Кстати не забудьте что это будет работать только если браузер поддерживает HTML5.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul Да, нашел такое же решение после статьи с англоязычного стака. Это связанно с тем, что страница подгружает .js раньше, чем .html. Еще очень важно чтобы "2d" было с маленькой написанно.